# C# Connect to remote SQL Server and get Databases

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database-connection

I am currently able to connect to a local SQL Server instance and get a list of Databases.  However, I am now trying to connect to a remote SQL Server Instance and get a list of its Databases.

I cant seem to get the SQLConnection correct.

```
using (var oSQLConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=123.45.67.890; User ID=sa; Password=password; ))
```

Below is my code that Im using for the local SQL Server Connection that works.

```
    private void btSQLListRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sDatabaseName = "";
        using (var oSQLConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost; Integrated Security=True;"))

        {
            oSQLConnection.Open();
            DataTable oDatabases = oSQLConnection.GetSchema("Databases");
            int iDBCount = oDatabases.Rows.Count;

            foreach (DataRow database in oDatabases.Rows)
            {
                sDatabaseName = database.Field<String>("database_name");
                short sDBID = database.Field<short>("dbid");
                DateTime dCreationDate = database.Field<DateTime>("create_date");

                if (sDatabaseName != "master" && sDatabaseName != "model" && sDatabaseName != "msdb" && sDatabaseName != "tempdb")
                {
                    lbSQLDBList.Items.Add(sDatabaseName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Error:

> ServerVersion  'oSQLConnection.ServerVersion' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'    string {System.InvalidOperationException}
>
> base   {"Invalid operation. The connection is closed."}    System.SystemException {System.InvalidOperationException}

Comment: What is the error you are receiving?  Also, you missed a close quote on the end of your connection string.

Comment: +  ServerVersion 'oSQLConnection.ServerVersion' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' string {System.InvalidOperationException}

Comment: +  base {"Invalid operation. The connection is closed."} System.SystemException {System.InvalidOperationException}  After setting oSQLConnection

Comment: Well, connection is closed is pretty self explanatory.  The connection object is no longer open.  Try opening it again, or refactoring so the connection object doesnt timeout or close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Data Source=123.45.67.890.100,+ [Port Number for IP access ex: "1433"];Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=master;User ID=sa;Password=password;

I think you are just missing a port number for access.

Comment: You don't need to specify the port number if it is the default.

Comment: Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL

Comment: for some reason when I switch to a local server I can connect without issues.  But when I try to connect to a remote server I get the connection problem.  This remote server is allowing remote connections.